# How to improve Java multi-threading performance? Time efficiency of saving/loading data from NoSQL database (like Redis) vs ArrayList?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, arraylist

I am evaluating an SDK and I need to cross compare ~15000 iris images stored in a gallery folder and generate the similarity scores as a 15000 x 15000 matrix.

So I pre-processed all the images and stored the processed blobs in an ArrayList. Then I'm using multiple threads with 2 'for' loops in the run method to call the 'compare' method (from SDK) and pass the index of an ArrayList as parameters to compare those respective blobs and save the integer return values in an excel sheet using Apache poi library. **The performance is very inefficient (each comparison takes ~40ms) and the whole task takes a lot of time (~100 days estimated with 8 cores running at 100%) to do all the 225,000,000 comparisons. Please help me understand this bottle neck.**

> **Multithreading code**

```
int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors); 
for(int i =0; i<processors; i++) { 
  //each thread compares 1875 images with 15000 images
  Runnable task = new Thread(bloblist,i*1875,i*1875+1874); 
  executor.execute(task);
}   
executor.shutdown();
```

> **Run Method**

```
public void run(){
 for(int i = startIndex; i<= lastIndex; i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<15000;j++){
        compare.compareIris(bloblist.get(i),bloblist.get(j));
        score= compare.getScore();
        //save result to Excel using Apache POI
        ...
        ...
        }
 }
}
```

*Please suggest me a time-efficient architecture to accomplish this task. Shall I store the blobs in a NoSQL DB or is there any alternate way to do this?*

Comment: Profile an smaller run and post the results. It is hard to guess without code or numbers

Comment: Does the sdk provide an stop-comparing floor value?

Comment: Do you have to store the data in Excel binary format using POI? It would be simpler to store the data in a text file (CSV) and then import it to Excel. However, that might not be the bottleneck; we would need to see some code.

Comment: What is `compare`? It should be per-thread, from the way you access it. Do you need to compare `i` to `j` and `j` to `i` both? Is there any synchronization that's not shown?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I tried that but then the file size was too large. However, I need to do some analysis on the data so I prefer to save the results directly into an excel sheet. And each thread would create its own excel file in this case.

Here's how the sample results look like **https://expirebox.com/download/f5cc0ec8dd2d03bedae930f72fb53d73.html**

Comment: Does comparing `i` to `j` and `j` to `i` yield different values?  If not you would only ever need to compare the images once.

Comment: @MichaelHibay To answer your question, the results are not symmetric so I would have to do both. This is because of the "compare" methods internal implementation, i and j are processed differently.

Comment: Probably the bottleneck is the compare. What exactly are you doing there? There's a good chance some clever preprocessing can change the runtime from O(n^2) to something smaller. If that doesn't work some GPU or vectorised approach (hard to do in java) would probably make the next big differences.

Comment: If the compare method does not provide a low-quality exit value as it is comparing, the more likely bottleneck is the compare as mentioned by @Voo. You would be looking at several boxes crunching. But without hard profiling numbers it is just chit-chat

Comment: Does the compare method require 40ms on one core, or does it use 8 cores.  If it only requires one core, why is the estimated time 104 days instead of 13 days?  Are all the blobs stored in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider adding some simple profiling to your code as a first step. Profiling libraries are great, but can be a little intimidating. All you really need to get started is:

```
public void run(){
 long sumCompare = 0;
 long sumSave = 0
 for(int i = startIndex; i<= lastIndex; i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<15000;j++){
        final long compareStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        compare.compareIris(bloblist.get(i),bloblist.get(j));
        score= compare.getScore();
        final long compareEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        compareSum += (compareEnd - compareStart);
        //save result to Excel using Apache POI
        ...
        ...
        final long saveEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        saveSum += (saveEnd - compareEnd);
        }
 }
System.out.println(String.format("Compare: %d; Save: %d", sumCompare, sumSave);
}
```

Maybe run this over a 100x100 grid instead to get a rough idea of where the bulk of your runtime is.

If it's the save step, I'd strongly recommend using a database as an intermediate step between computing the score and exporting it to a spreadsheet. A NoSQL database would work, although I'd also encourage you to look at something like SQLite, just for simplicity's sake. (Many NoSQL databases are designed to offer advantages across a *cluster* of database nodes while working with very large datasets; if you're storing write-only data on one node, SQL may be your best bet.)

If the bottleneck is the compute step, it will be more difficult to improve performance. If the blobs don't all fit comfortably in RAM along with whatever RAM the comparisons consume, you may be paying the price of swapping this data onto and off-of disk. You may see a small improvement by having each thread take work "off of a queue", rather than starting with a pre-assigned block:

```
final int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors); 
final AtomicLong nextCompare = new AtomicLong(0);

for(int i =0; i<processors; i++) { 
  Runnable task = new Thread(bloblist, nextCompare); 
  executor.execute(task);
}   
executor.shutdown();
```

---

```
public void run(){
  while (true) {
    final long taskNum = nextCompare.getAndIncrement();
    if (taskNum >= 15000 * 15000) {
      return;
    }
    final long i = Math.floor(taskNum/15000);
    final long j = taskNum % 15000;
    compare.compareIris(bloblist.get(i),bloblist.get(j));
    score = compare.getScore();
    // Save score, etc.)
  }
}
```

This will result in all threads working on blobs stored relatively close together in memory. In this way, no thread is evicting data from the cache that another thread will require in the near future. You are, however, paying the price of locking the `AtomicLong`; if memory thrashing *wasn't* your issue, this will likely be a bit slower.